# LDAP constraint violation when forwarding email

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2003

I've got a user who wants his email forwarded from our Exchange server to a mail server controlled by another organization. A contact has been created for him on another domain in the forest (yes, complications, no I can't do anything about it). When I attempt to set the forwarding address to that contact, and apply it, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
 Microsoft Active Directory - Exchange Extension
---------------------------
A constraint violation occurred.



Facility: LDAP Provider
ID no: 8007202f
Microsoft Active Directory - Exchange Extension

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

This same process normally works with other users, with contacts located both on my domain, and the same remote domain that holds this user's contact.

Comment: And when I tried to demonstrate the problem to someone else, it worked on their machine. Go figure.

Comment: where are you setting the contact's address: in ADU&C? do you have full permissions to the domain where the contact object is homed?

Comment: The contact is not created by me. I don't set the address, I just utilize the contact. I have full rights to my domain, but no rights on the domain where the contact object is located.

Comment: So when you say "when I attempt to set the forwarding address", what exactly are you doing if not editing the e-mail address associated with the contact object?

Comment: In ADU&C, you can select an object to forward a user's email to (either another user, or a contact). I'm editting the field that does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen LDAP Constrain Violations can occur for two main reasons:

1. The data is invalid, malformed, or does not meet the schema constraints for some reason
2. The data is visible to you, but is not visible to the DC you are making the change on.

If it works/worked on another machine, or if it worked when you tried later in the day, then it is likely to be the 2nd option.  DC discovery, Global Catalog Replication, and Domain Replication in the extra domain could cause your client to have different visibility of the intended object when compared to the DC.

Answer (score 1):

Create a contact in Exchange Server 2003 and assign email of user of Exchange Server 2007, and follow steps in 2nd para of the question.
Reference: [Forwarding email from Exchange Server 2003 to Exchange Server 2007/2010/2013](https://serverfault.com/questions/544578/forwarding-email-from-exchange-server-2003-to-exchange-server-2007-2010-2013)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have rights to the domain where the contact object is homed, you won't be able to edit its properties. Try this for a test: create a contact in a domain where you have Domain Admin rights or better, then edit its forwarding address from the machine that's giving you the constraint violation error and report back on what happens.

Comment: I don't need to edit the contact object's properties. The contact exists with all the proper data already. Additionally, as stated, the problem was resolved when attempting to demonstrate the problem on a different machine.

Lastly, the procedure is the same whether the contact is on my domain, or the remote domain in the forest. Only difference is who creates the contact (local contact is created by me, remote by someone else). This procedure is actually scripted, so there is literally no deviation.