# Forwarding email from Exchange Server 2003 to Exchange Server 2007/2010/2013

Tags: exchange-2003, mail-forwarding

I have two Exchange Servers - Exchange Server 2003 and Exchange Server 2007. I want to forward any email that comes in Exchange Server 2003 to Exchange Server 2007. After getting an idea on how to forward an email to Exchange Server 2007, I will implement this technique to forward an email to Exchange Server 2010/2013. I have done all the basic steps like 'Raise Forest Functional Level' in domain.msc, 'Raise Domain Functional Level' in domain.msc, Adding forwarders in dnsmgmt.msc, Creating a new trust in domain.msc, Configuring 'Send Connectors' & 'Receive Connectors' & creating 'MX record' in both the domains.

I want to forward email from Exchange Server 2003 to Exchange Server 2007. I went to 'Exchange General' tab of 'Properties' of the user in ADUC in Exchange 2003, clicked on 'Delivery Options', selected 'Forward To', clicked on 'Modify', chose the user to forward emails to, checked on 'Deliver messages to both forwarding address and mailbox', clicked on 'OK'. Now, when I click on 'Apply' in the 'Properties' this message box appears:

> A Constraint violation occurred. Facility LDAP Provider. ID No.
>   8007202f. Microsoft Active Directory Exchange Exchange Extension

Comment: You really need to include the `why`.  Are you wanting to migrate from 2003 to 2007, etc.?  Or are you wanting to co-exist and forward email from one mailbox to another?  What's the goal here?

Comment: The second one. I want to forward email from Exchange Server 2003 to Exchange Server 2007. I went to 'Exchange General' tab of 'Properties' of the user in ADUC in Exchange 2003, clicked on 'Delivery Options', selected 'Forward To', clicked on 'Modify', chose the user to forward emails to, checked on 'Deliver messages to both forwarding address and mailbox', clicked on 'OK'. Now, when I click on 'Apply' in the 'Properties' this message box appears: 'Microsoft Active Directory Exchange Exchange Extension'.

Comment: A Constraint violation occurred. Facility LDAP Provider. ID No. 8007202f. Microsoft Active Directory Exchange Exchange Extension

Comment: BTW is there any difference between the two possibilities that you have stated?

Comment: Sure...big differences.  One involves migrating mailboxes, the other is simply forwarding email between accounts.  I haven't seen that error to be honest, and exchange 2003 is too old for me to recall it well enough.  Maybe someone else might know.

Comment: @user2744197, if this is the start of a migration, you haven't read the docs - you're simply attacking this from the wrong direction. Microsoft has a lot of good documents on how to transition from Exchange 2003 to 2007/2010, do yourself a favor and read them before doing anything else.

Comment: @Trondh : As stated earlier, which is clear for any educated person, I want to co-exist and forward email form one mailbox to another.

Comment: @TheCleaner : OK. Its on www (the error). But nothing specific about it. All things are generalized. And because very few people have worked on Exchange Server 2003 & there no support, I am facing problems.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time. I got the answer to this question. I don't have even 1 year of experience in my company and have just started using this product (I have worked on projects unrelated to this). Some people from development and testing team have also contributed a collective time of more than 2 months on this issue. The solution is to create a contact in Exchange Server 2003 and assign email of user of Exchange Server 2007. And follow steps in 2nd para of the question. Again, Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: @user2744197 - If you found the issue and a fix for your "constraint" error it is acceptable and encouraged that you post it as the answer to your own question and accept that answer.  It could help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a contact in Exchange Server 2003 and assign email of user of Exchange Server 2007, and follow steps in 2nd para of the question.